# Translating Pytorch program into Keras: different results

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, pytorch, image-segmentation

I have translated a pytorch program into keras.

A working Pytorch program:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from skimage import segmentation

np.random.seed(1)
torch.manual_seed(1)


fi = "in.jpg"


class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inChannel, n_outChannel):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()

        self.seq = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(n_inChannel, n_outChannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_outChannel),

            nn.Conv2d(n_outChannel, n_outChannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_outChannel),

            nn.Conv2d(n_outChannel, n_outChannel, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_outChannel)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.seq(x)


im = cv2.imread(fi)
data = torch.from_numpy(np.array([im.transpose((2, 0, 1)).astype('float32')/255.]))
data = data.cuda()

labels = segmentation.slic(im, compactness=100, n_segments=10000)
labels = labels.flatten()
u_labels = np.unique(labels)
label_indexes = np.array([np.where(labels == u_label)[0] for u_label in u_labels])

n_inChannel = 3
n_outChannel = 100

model = MyNet(n_inChannel, n_outChannel)
model.cuda()
model.train()
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)

label_colours = np.random.randint(255,size=(100,3))

for batch_idx in range(100):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model( data )[ 0 ]
    output = output.permute( 1, 2, 0 ).view(-1, n_outChannel)
    ignore, target = torch.max( output, 1 )

    im_target = target.data.cpu().numpy()
    nLabels = len(np.unique(im_target))

    im_target_rgb = np.array([label_colours[ c % 100 ] for c in im_target]) # correct position of "im_target"
    im_target_rgb = im_target_rgb.reshape( im.shape ).astype( np.uint8 )

    for inds in label_indexes:
        u_labels_, hist = np.unique(im_target[inds], return_counts=True) 
        im_target[inds] = u_labels_[np.argmax(hist, 0)]

    target = torch.from_numpy(im_target)
    target = target.cuda()    

    loss = loss_fn(output, target)

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print (batch_idx, '/', 100, ':', nLabels, loss.item())

    if nLabels <= 3:
        break         
fo = "out.jpg"
cv2.imwrite(fo, im_target_rgb)
```

(source: https://github.com/kanezaki/pytorch-unsupervised-segmentation/blob/master/demo.py)

My translation into Keras:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import segmentation
from keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Input, Reshape
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as k
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from skimage import io
from keras.models import Sequential

np.random.seed(0)

fi = "in.jpg"
im = cv2.imread(fi).astype(float)/255.

labels = segmentation.slic(im, compactness=100, n_segments=10000)
labels = labels.flatten()
print (labels.shape)
u_labels = np.unique(labels)

label_indexes = [np.where(labels == u_label)[0] for u_label in np.unique(labels)]

n_channels = 100

model = Sequential()

model.add (  Conv2D(n_channels, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=im.shape, padding='same'))    
model.add( BatchNormalization())

model.add( Conv2D(n_channels, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))    
model.add( BatchNormalization())

model.add( Conv2D(n_channels, kernel_size=1, padding='same'))
model.add( BatchNormalization())

model.add( Reshape((im.shape[0] * im.shape[1], n_channels)))

img = np.expand_dims(im,0)
print (img.shape)
output = model.predict(img)

print (output.shape)

im_target = np.argmax(output[0], 1)
print (im_target.shape)

for inds in label_indexes:
    u_labels_, hist = np.unique(im_target[inds], return_counts=True)
    im_target[inds] = u_labels_[np.argmax(hist, 0)]

def custom_loss(loss_target, loss_output):
  return k.categorical_crossentropy(target=k.stack(loss_target), output=k.stack(loss_output), from_logits=True)


model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.9), loss=custom_loss)

model.fit(img, output, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

pred_result = model.predict(x=[img])[0]
print (pred_result.shape)

target = np.argmax(pred_result, 1)
print (target.shape)

nLabels = len(np.unique(target))

label_colours = np.random.randint(255, size=(100, 3))

im_target_rgb = np.array([label_colours[c % 100] for c in im_target])

im_target_rgb = im_target_rgb.reshape(im.shape).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite("out.jpg", im_target_rgb)
```

*However, Keras output is really different than of pytorch*

Input image:

[image: input image]

Pytorch result:

[image: pytorch result]

Keras result:

[image: keras result]

Could someone help me for this translation?

**Edit 1:**

```
I corrected two errors as advised by @sebrockm
1. removed `relu` from last conv layer
2. added `from_logits = True` in the loss function
```

Also, changed the no. of conv layers from 4 to 3 to match with the original code.

```
However, output image did not improve than before and the `loss` are resulted in negative:

Epoch 99/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 92ms/step - loss: -22.8380

Epoch 100/100    
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 99ms/step - loss: -23.039
```

**I think that the Keras code lacks connection between model and output. However, could not figure out to make this connection.**

Answer (score 1):

Two major mistakes that I see (likely related):

1. The last convolutional layer in the original model does not have an activation function, while your translation uses `relu`.
2. The original model uses `CrossEntropyLoss` as loss function, while your model uses `categorical_crossentropy` with `logits=False` (a default argument). Without mathematical background the difference is tricky to explain, but in short: `CrossEntropyLoss` has a `softmax` built in, that's why the model doesn't have one on the last layer. To do the same in keras, use `k.categorical_crossentropy(..., logits=True)`. "logits" means the input values are expected **not** to be "softmaxed", i.e. all values can be arbitrary. Currently, your loss function expects the output values to be "softmaxed", i.e. all values must be between 0 and 1 (and sum up to 1).

### Update:

One other mistake, likely a huge one: In Keras, you calculate the `output` once in the beginning and never change it from there on. Then you train your model to fit on this initially generated output.

In the original pytorch code, `target` (which is the variable being trained on) gets updated in every training loop. 
So, you cannot use Keras' `fit` method which is designed for doing the entire training for you (given *fixed* training data). You will have to replicate the training loop manually, just as it is done in the pytorch code. I'm not sure if this is easily doable with the [API](https://keras.io/models/model/) Keras provides. `train_on_batch` is one method you surely will need in your manual loop. You will have to do some more work, I'm afraid...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I corrected the mistakes you have pointed out. Also, changed the number of conv layers from 4 to 3 to match the original code. Please see Edit 1. However, output is not improved than before!

Comment: @torch2keras see my update. I'm afraid there is some fancy logic going on in the manual training loop of pytorch. You will have to replicate that in Keras as close as possible. Just calling `fit` won't work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great ideas. I have one question, in Pytorch code, does the `target` is being updated from lower to upper direction? Because, the  'im_target` is retrieved after the `hist` refinement, the resulting image degrades. I mean, why the `im_target` should be retrived from the position which is before the `hist` refinement? The common logic would be to retrieve it after the `hist` refinement.

Comment: @torch2keras Unfortunately, I do not understand at all what the author of this code is doing there, why they are doing this, and why it works. Sorry, but I can't help with that. But looks pretty interesting...